# ¿Cómo mostrar información de un solo usuario en php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un problema con este código. Quiero mostrar la información de un usuario logeado, pero me aparece un error.

Básicamente ésta sería la consulta que estoy realizando dentro de un perfil:

```
             $consulta = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id_usuario";
             $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

             while($dato = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

            ?>
       <ul>
           <li>Nombre:    <span> <?php echo $dato['nombre'] ?> </span></li>
           <li>Correo:    <span> <?php echo $dato['correo'] ?> </span></li>
           <li>Dirección: <span> <?php echo $dato['direccion'] ?> </span></li>
           <li>Teléfono:  <span> <?php echo $dato['telefono'] ?> </span></li>
       </ul>
       <?php } ?>
```

pero cuando entro en dicho perfil me aparece el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id_usuario in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\01_Codes\bienvenido.php on line 67 Warning:
>   mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\01_Codes\bienvenido.php on line 72

Agradecería muchísimo si me ayudan a resolver este problema!!

Comment: justo despues de la varibale `$resultado` escribe lo siguiente para ver que error esta generandose `if (!$resultado) {
    echo( mysqli_error($conexion));
}`

Comment: buen día gracias por responder

esto es lo que aparece
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: duda, si estas declarando la variable `$id_usuario` es decir al momento de usarlo en tu consulta si existe y tiene valor asignado?

Comment: prueba dentro de ese mismo bloque de código asignarle un valor fijo a tu variable, es decir que tenga esto: `$id_usuario = 1` ejecuta de nuevo la consulta y comentanos

Comment: $id_usuario = $_SESSION["id_usuario"]; 

esta la tengo al principio antes de $consulta

Comment: como te decia asignale un valor fijo para ver si el problema es que no le este llegando ningún valor, entonces ponle como te indico arriba que sea igual a 1 y ejecuta de nuevo el código

Comment: pues desaparece el primer error y muestra lo siguiente

Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\01_Codes\bienvenido.php on line 74

Comment: añade en tu pregunta la estructura de la tabla, por que entonces el fallo es que estas escribiendo mal el nombre de la columna, seguro que la columna en tu tabla se llama `id`?

Comment: listo ya está la imagen
la columna se llama id

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que dice el error, el valor de `$_SESSION['id_usuario']` no está definido. Tienes que comprobar que el código que crea esa variable funcione correctamente.

Pero lo más importante es que tienes dos fallos de seguridad muy graves en tu código:

El primero, guardar las contraseñas de tus usuarios en texto plano. Debes utilizar un cifrado seguro para las contraseñas para garantizar la seguridad de tus usuarios ante posibles hackeos, sobre todo por el siguiente fallo que tienes. Usa la función `password_hash($contraseña, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` para generar el `$hash` que almacenarás (en lugar de la contraseña). Usa `password_verify($contraseña, $hash)` para verificar si la contraseña introducida por el usuario coincide con la registrada (en lugar de comparar las contraseñas).

El segundo fallo es utilizar directamente el valor de variables como `$_SESSION`, `$_COOKIES`, `$_POST` o `$_GET` directamente en una consulta SQL sin validar el valor o al menos filtrarlo. Estas variables pueden ser modificadas fácilmente en el cliente. Un atacante puede introducir y ejecutar fácilmente código en tu base de datos que le permita obtener acceso a todos tus datos. Para solucionar este problema deberías filtrar la variable con `mysqli_real_escape_string($variable)`, utilizar comillas al rededor de la variable en las consultas (ej: `"SELECT name, age FROM users WHERE id = '$uid'"`, fíjate que `$uid` está dentro de comillas simples) y comprobar si el valor recibido tiene el formato esperado comprobando el valor (texto, número entero, decimal, email, url, contraseña), longitud de la cadena, etc.

Comment: No es necesario pasar la variable entre comillas simples, aún sin ellas debe funcionar

Comment: hacer eso no brinda seguridad en ningún sentido, el único modo de tener seguridad es empezar por usar sentencias preparadas

Comment: No digo que poner comillas dobles sea hacerte invulnerable, pero sin duda protegen más que no ponerlas. Una vez escapada la variable con `mysqli_real_escape_string()` el usuario aún puede poner `;` para cerrar la sentencia y empezar otra. No puedes negar que evitas ese problema al poner las comillas.

Comment: te invito a leer las publicaciones de los usuarios de mas alto puntaje, de esta comunidad donde explican que de hecho `mysqli_real_escape_string` no ayuda practicamente en nada

Comment: bueno gracias por responder
pero digamos que la verificación por el momento no es lo que tengo en mente si, solo quiero que cuando un usuario inicie sesión aparezca la información básica del mismo. 

solucioné lo de arriba  como  *Shadow dijo $id_usuario = 1; me sale el resultado del primer campo registrado, pero la cuestión es que aparezca para cada uno con su propia información

Comment: Ayuda a escapar ciertos caracteres, es una función muy simple pero ayuda, del mismo modo que ayudan las comillas aunque por separado no sirvan de mucho. Por eso también he dicho que compruebe el valor de las variables validando formato, longitud, etc. que es lo más seguro, no solo para evitar ataques sino para asegurar que los datos son correctos. En el caso del ejemplo bastaría con un simple `intval($_SESSION['id_usuario'])` para garantizar la seguridad de la consulta.

Comment: Jeffrey, como dije al principio de mi respuesta, el error no está en el código que has puesto en tu pregunta. El error está al definir `$_SESSION['id_usuario']`. Pon esa parte del código.

Comment: esa variable la tengo como $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

Comment: Esa es la línea donde defines `$id_usuario`. Te estoy preguntando por el código donde creas `$_SESSION['id_usuario']`, que supongo que es al iniciar sesión.